# Как грамотно сделать кэширование доски обьявлений?

Tags: кэширование, php

Доска обьявлений выглядет как блог, т.е. на странице 30 обьявлений а внизу идет нумерация страниц.

Как сделать кэширование этих страниц с нумерацией внизу?

Если можно, примеры кода.

Comment: А зачем? Скорость получения этих страниц очень маленькая?

Comment: Я бы кешировал только сами объявления, а не листинг объявлений.

Comment: Сами обьявления кэшируются

Но очень большая нагрузка идет на страницы с выводом списка обьявлений и там еще сортировка есть

В итоге время загрузки иногда достигает 40 сек

Это жесть, да еще гугл сильно грузит систему

Answer (score 1):

Сохранять те страницы (части, содержащие сами объявления) в файлы, и инклудить через SSI в темплейт страницы.